# Parsley js remote set status

Tags: javascript, parsley.js

I have the following input field:

```
<input type="text"  class="form-control" id="UserLogin" maxlength="32" data-ajax-name="login" data-parsley-remote-options='{ "type": "POST",  "data": { "request":"ajax", "field": "login" } }' data-parsley-errors-messages-disabled="1" data-parsley-remote-validator="validateUsername" data-parsley-remote="1" data-parsley-trigger="focusout" name="data[User][login]" data-parsley-id="2315">
```

And the following script:

```
jQuery('#UserLogin').parsley().addAsyncValidator('validateUsername', function (xhr) {
    var UserLogin = $('#UserLogin').parsley();
    window.ParsleyUI.removeError(UserLogin,'errorUsername');
    if(xhr.status == '200')
        return 200;
    if(xhr.status == '404')
        window.ParsleyUI.addError(UserLogin,'errorUsername',xhr.responseText);
    },'/User/validationMethod'
);
```

In my php, I have the following (for testing purposes):

```
    public function validationMethod()
{
    print ('404');
}
```

Now this works fine but it has an issue. the responseText is 404 not the actual status (which is 200)

So how do I change the status to be 404?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the status code, see the [doc](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.header.php)

The text you return is not the status of your response.

> header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");